Schwartz kernel of spectral projection of Laplacian and integrated density of states
I am considering the Dirichlet Laplacian $\Delta$ on some smooth domain $U$. For now assume that $U$ is bounded, and later we will change that.
For $E\in\mathbb R$, I can use the functional calculus (or spectral theorem) to define the operator $\chi_{(-\infty, E]}(\Delta)$, which basically corresponds to projecting onto all eigenspaces up to energy $E$. This operator has an associated Schwartz kernel $S(x,y)$, i.e., an integral kernel:
$$\chi_{(-\infty, E]}(\Delta)f=\int_{y\in U} S(x,y)f(y)dy.$$
I am interested in a relation between $S(x,y)$ and the integrated density of states of $\Delta$. Since the spectrum of $\Delta$ is discrete, the integrated density of states is just the normalized counting function:
$$N(E)=\frac{\#\{\lambda\in \text{spec}(\Delta):\lambda \leq E\}}{|U|}.$$
Using some elementary arguments, I was able to show that
$$S(x,y)=\sum_{\lambda\leq E}g_{\lambda}(x)\overline{g_{\lambda}(y)},$$
where the summation is over all eigenvalues up to $E$ and $g_{\lambda}$ is the noramlized eigenfunction associated to $\lambda$. Using this identity, straightforward integration shows that
$$N(E)=\frac{\int_{x\in U} S(x,x)dx}{|U|}.$$
So far so good. But my real interest is actually to study $U$ which is unbounded, and so the spectrum of $\Delta$ is no longer discrete. In the unbounded setting, we define the integrated density of states as
$$N(E)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\#\{\lambda\in \text{spec}(\Delta|_{U_n}):\lambda \leq E\}}{|U_n|},$$
where the increasing sequence of subdomains $U_n\subset U$ converges to $U$ "nicely" (don't worry about technicalities, just assume it makes sense in our setting).
In this case, the relation above between $S(x,y),N(E)$ clearly no longer holds, as there are (usually) no eigenfunctions and $|U|$ is infinite, so the expression no longer makes sense.
I believe that one can replace the summation over $g_\lambda$ with integration over spectral projections (with respect to certain spectral measures), but I am not very well versed in these sorts of things. I am also not sure what would replace the normalization factor, as it is infinite now.
Does anyone have any idea on how to prove a similar relation in the infinite setting? Or if it already exists somewhere, I'd also appreciate a reference.
Thanks in advance.

Consider Math Overflow if no satisfactory answers are given.

Essentially, you want to generalise the fact that $\text{Tr}(P) = \text{rk}(P)$ for a projector $P$. The issue is that in the continuum limit, the traces and ranks are infinite, so you need to “renormalize” them in order to get meaningful results. Physically, you need to replace extensive quantities by extensive ones (instead of absolute numbers, rather number per unit volume).
To build intuition, you can look at $\Omega = \mathbb R^n$. Your projection $P$ is a brick wall filter in Fourier space. Using the convention:
$$
f(x) = \int \hat f(k)e^{ikx}\frac{d^nk}{(2\pi)^n} \quad \hat f(k) = \int f(x)e^{-ikx}d^nx
$$
you have:
$$
\hat{Pf}(k) = \chi_{[0,E]}(k^2)\hat f(k)\\
S(x,y) = \frac1{(2\pi)^n}\left|\sqrt E\frac{x-y}{2\pi}\right|^{-n/2}J_{n/2}(\sqrt E|x-y|)
$$
Using the definition:
$$
N(E) = \int_{k^2<E}\frac{d^nk}{(2\pi)^n}
$$
you will also get:
$$
N(E) = S(0,0)
$$
which follows directly from the definition of the Fourier transform at $x=0$. The reason why things simplify here is that $S(x,x)$ is constant, so the "density" is any value, like $S(0,0)$.
You can formalise this using projection valued measures. From the spectral theorem, on an unbounded domain, you write:
$$
-\Delta = \int Ed\mu(E)
$$
So you can define:
$$
P = \mu((-\infty,E))
$$
To get the trace “density”, a natural approach is to define it as:
$$
T:= \lim\frac1{|\Omega_n|}\int_{\Omega_n} S(x,x)dx
$$
with $\Omega_n$ sub domains of finite measure “converging” to your final infinite domain.
Similarly, you need to redefine the number of eigenmodes in a continuous spectrum. Following the previous example, it is probably easiest to think in terms of the multiplicative operator formulation. Now you can replace the discrete counting measure by an integral. You still get the desired equality thanks to the general property that trace is base invariant.
